# How to empty an array-like object, cross-browser (IE8)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, javascript-objects, array-splice

I have an object which is array-like. This means that it has numeric properties (`0`, `1`, `2`...) and a `length` property.

In its prototype, I declare a method to clear it, like so:

```
'clear': function() {
    Array.prototype.splice.call(this, 0, this.length);
    return this;
}
```

This works as expected in most browsers but not Internet Explorer.

Take a perfectly valid array-like object:

```
var arrayLike = {
    length: 3,
    '0': 'a',
    '1': 'b',
    '2': 'c'
};
```

And splice it clear:

```
Array.prototype.splice.call(arrayLike, 0, arrayLike.length);
```

On a standards compliant browser, this is the correct result:

```
arrayLike.length ==     0    ;
arrayLike[0]     == undefined;
arrayLike[1]     == undefined;
arrayLike[2]     == undefined;
```

But in IE 8, this is what you get:

```
arrayLike.length ==  0 ; // (!!)
arrayLike[0]     == 'a';
arrayLike[1]     == 'b';
arrayLike[2]     == 'c';
```

Yes, it does not even either work or not, it works as much as it wants to.

Now, I think `Array.prototype.splice.call` is the only way to clear an array-like object natively. I could polyfill it in a private copy conditionally for IE8, maybe (incurring a one-time performance hit for other browsers, but only once).

Or maybe there is another way of clearing the object? That is also native in IE8? Is there something I'm not seeing?

Ps: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Camilo/sJkwz/) for you to run in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

IE is messed up... It seems even if you extend an array object, IE screws up splice. See my testing below:

```
// create an object constructor
var arrayLike = function() {
    this.clear = function() {
        this.splice( 0, this.length );
    };
};
// use prototypical inheritance to inherit array functionality
arrayLike.prototype = [];
arrayLike.constructor = arrayLike;

// testing clear method fails...
var arrayLikeObject = new arrayLike();
arrayLikeObject.push( 'foo' );
console.log( arrayLikeObject[ 0 ] ); // outputs foo
arrayLikeObject.clear();
console.log( arrayLikeObject[ 0 ] ); // outputs foo

// yet the same method works on a normal array
var test = [];
test.push( 'foo2' );
test.splice( 0, test.length );
console.log( test[0] ); // outputs undefined
```

what the hell IE...

Comment: Yes, my feelings exactly. Besides, for example `push` works! Works just right. And `splice` does only half the job (which is even more wtf-ish).

Comment: @CamiloMartin One thing you may want to consider is simply using an object as a wrapper for an actual array. You could add the methods you need to get, set, clear, etc. It wouldn't be ideal syntactically, but you would have complete control over the functionality.

Comment: Well, my idea is to check for the bug (by running a small test) and updating a "protoSplice" property of my library's scope with a version that works on IE8. Because, some methods (like `push`) work in a generic way just fine (and I don't want to lose native performance on other browsers). I'm working on it right now :)

Answer (score 0):

<s>My gut feeling is that you shouldn't be using `Array.prototype.splice.call` on an object that isn't an `Array`. To me, that seems hackish.</s>

<s>Yes, it probably works in most browsers but you're trying to perform an operation designed for one prototype on an object that isn't of that prototype. I'm no fan of IE, but this looks to me like hackery so you can't cry foul when it doesn't work out.</s>

My 2¢ is to either create the new "`Array`-like" object using `Array` as the prototype, example:

```
var ArrayLike = function(){
    this.push.apply(this, arguments);
};
ArrayLike.prototype = Array.prototype;
ArrayLike.constructor = function(){};
ArrayLike.prototype.clear = function(){
    // Array.prototype.splice.call(this, 0, this.length);
    this.splice(0, this.length); // all of Array's methods are available to ArrayLike
    return this;
}

var arrayLike = new ArrayLike('a', 'b', 'c');
console.log(arrayLike.length);  // 3
arrayLike.clear();              // clear
console.log(arrayLike.length);  // 0
```

...or write your own method.

Comment: ECMAScript specifically mentions using `Array.prototype` methods on array-like objects as being permitted. In other words, the methods are meant to be somewhat generic, so that they're not restricted only to native Array instances.

Comment: I stand corrected: "The splice function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its this value be an Array object." http://bit.ly/kbGCer Still, the above will give you the benefits of the native `Array.prototype.splice` in IE8.

Comment: Well, would be good if it worked. Two things: first, I'm already extending the prototype as mentioned, but most importantly, you only checked `.length`. As shown in my question, the splice call works for `length` (sets it to zero), but the array properties remain unchanged. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxXxF/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Man, this is funny. `Array.prototype.splice` is broken in a ***very weird way*** in IE8.

I have to show you this (skip it if you want, solution below).

As you have seen, this will alert "a" in IE, right?

```
// Create an array-like object.
var arrayLike = {
    length: 1,
    '0': 'a'
};

// Clean it with splice. This should work in ES5.
Array.prototype.splice.call(arrayLike, 0, 2);

// Note that IE does set the length to zero. We need to check an item.
alert(arrayLike[0]);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Camilo/mmKbR/).

Now, what if we set it to an invalid length? Specifically for this effect, "3" ("2" will produce the same results in IE8).

Now, what does *this* alert in IE8?

```
var arrayLike = {
    length: 3,      // <--
    '0': 'a'
};

Array.prototype.splice.call(arrayLike, 0, 2);

alert(arrayLike[0]);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Camilo/3U8SQ/).

In any case, I'm not going to rely on that weird way of working, I don't want to have a horribly strange bug in production. **This is how you fix it:**

First, you have your code wrapped in an IIFE right? You should. Second, check you have a private copy of `Array.prototype.splice`. I declare these things at the beginning of my IIFE.

```
// Call it whatever you want.
var protoSplice = Array.prototype.splice;
```

Then, on some initialization method (or at any time you want, make sure it's before you use it), call a polyfill method.

```
polyfill();
```

Which calls tests and fixes.

```
function polyfill() {
    // ...
    genericSpliceWorks() || fixGenericSplice();
    // ...
}
```

Here are the methods it uses:

```
function genericSpliceWorks() {

    // Create an array-like object.
    var arrayLike = {
    length: 1,
    '0': true
    };

    // Clean it with splice. This should work in ES5.
    protoSplice.call(arrayLike, 0, 2);

    // Note that IE does set the length to 0. We need to check an item.
    return !arrayLike[0];

}

function fixGenericSplice() {

    // Re-set our local protoSplice variable to something that works.
    // Note: this implementation only works with the first two arguments
    // of splice. This means that it does not add extra elements to the
    // array. It's as much as I need.
    protoSplice = function(index, count) {

        // If count is more than zero, run until it's zero, decrementing
        // each time.
        while (count--) {

            // Remove an array item from index, while incrementing index
            // for the next time.
            delete this[index++];

            // Decrement the length.
            this.length--;

        }

    };

}
```

Ta-da! It works now :)